# multiple versions of Mongo

Tags: mongodb

When I start the mongo shell from ~/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.5/bin, it starts up version 2.4.5

```
 ./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
```

That's the version I just downloaded.However, when I run the mongo command from anywhere else in my terminal it starts a different version. I think this is because I (obviously) installed Mongo previously.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
```

What do I need to do to make 2.4.5 respond to 'mongo' from anywhere in the terminal (i.e. to replace 2.2.0 with 2.4.5)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why you can't have multiple concurrent releases of mongo installed.
 You can have multiple versions of mongo and each running a different storage engine and also participate in a replica set.

Here are 3 installations on my mac
e.g.

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 18 rohitsood  staff    612 Aug 21 18:53 mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.3
drwxr-xr-x@  6 rohitsood  staff    204 Jan  4 20:25 mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.8
drwxr-xr-x@  8 rohitsood  staff    272 Jan  7 12:31 mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.0
```

if you want to start a mongod instance that maps to version 3.2 (the latest) then ensure your path points to it.

**Go to you Home (~) folder and open the ".profile" file to make these changes**

Here's what mine looks like for reference

```
#Set up MongoDB
#export MONGODB_HOME=/Users/rohitsood/servers/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.3
#export MONGODB_HOME=/Users/rohitsood/servers/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.8
export MONGODB_HOME=/Users/rohitsood/servers/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.0
export PATH=${MONGODB_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Open a new terminal - and mongo should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to update my path in bash_profile file to the location of the newer version

```
export PATH="/path/to/monogdb/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Why didn't you just uninstall your old MongoDB if your not using it?