# Install multiple versions of MongoDB on linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

How can we setup multiple versions of MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04?

MongoDB 3.4.1 is already up and running on my system and wanted to setup MongoDB 2.6 for other application. Because our Application running on MongoDB 2.6 is having DB driver which is not compatible with MongoDB 3.4 hence wanted run both MongoDB version on same linux server.

Tried to follow below link but couldn't succeed.

1. [How can I install two versions of mongodb parallely in Ubuntu 12.04
   ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042407/how-can-i-install-two-versions-of-mongodb-parallely-in-ubuntu-12-04)
2. [multiple versions of Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199383/multiple-versions-of-mongo)
3. [multiple instances of Mongo DB on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124610/multiple-instances-of-mongo-db-on-same-server)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do that, you must have both versions of MongoDB available on your system.

For instance, let's say you have downloaded the 2.6 version binaries to `/opt/mongo/26/` and the other version's at `/opt/mongo/34/`, you could run both versions of the database daemon on different ports:

```
/opt/mongo/26/mongod --dbpath /data/26/ --port 27017
/opt/mongo/34/mongod --dbpath /data/34/ --port 28018
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do.

### 1. Choose version:

- Community: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive
- Enterprise: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise/releases/archive

### 2. Install and Configuration

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to install mongodb Community ver 2.6.12

#### Installing:

```
    $ cd ~/Downloads
    $ curl -O http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz
    $ tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz
    $ mv mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.12 2.6.12
    $ cd /opt && mkdir -p mongodb
    $ cd ~/Downloads
    $ cp -R 2.6.12 /opt/mongodb
    $ cp /mongod.conf /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/
```

#### Configuration:

Configuration options on version <3.0 is different with version >3.0 so I googled it. This is what I had.

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27018
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

On this file, you need change systemLog.path, net.port and net.bindIp to your own. One important thing is we cannot run 2 versions at same time with same port. So here I set `27018` for older version.

Put it wherever you want, I did:

```
$ cp ~/mongod.conf /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/
```

DON'T RUN THIS because it will overwrite current mongodb version commands

```
$ export PATH=/opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin:$PATH
```

Create data and log directories and set permission.

```
$ mkdir -p /data/db
$ mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb
```

#### Running:

Now you can start 2.6 version with command.

```
$ /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongod --fork --dbpath /data/db --config /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/mongod.conf
```

It is too long, isn't it? So make it shorter with alias.

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
or
$ sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add this to file

```
alias mongo26="/opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongo --port 27018"
alias mongoRestore26="/opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongorestore --port 27018"
alias mongoDump26="/opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongodump --port 27018"
alias startMongo26="/opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongod --fork --dbpath /data/db --config /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/mongod.conf"
alias stopMongo26="/opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongod --dbpath /data/db --shutdown"

alias nanoMongo="nano /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/mongod.conf"
alias tailMongo="tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
alias tailMongo26="tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
```

Apply these alias

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
or
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now we can simply start mongodb version 2.6 by

```
$ startMongo26
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 1049481
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

Run shell version 2.6

```
$ mongo26
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27018/test
>
```

Run shell current version

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("3ae6094f-86dc-4741-aa72-1e48efc5273a") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.3
>
```

### 3.Troubleshooting

- Cannot start by `startMongo26` please check log at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 1049890
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

Check log at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

- If log has this line:

```
2021-02-26T15:51:13.493-0700 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

This is because your current user doesn't have permission to run and write into this directory. You can set permission to /data/db or change directory. I changed to ~/datamongo

```
$ /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/bin/mongod --fork --dbpath ~/datamongo --config /opt/mongodb/2.6.12/mongod.conf
```

- Do the same with error on `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

#### Cannot shutdown by `stopMongo26`

```
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

Do this:

```
$ mongo26
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27018/test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.shutdownServer()
2021-02-26T15:45:19.738-0700 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
2021-02-26T15:45:19.742-0700 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27018 (127.0.0.1) failed
2021-02-26T15:45:19.742-0700 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27018, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2021-02-26T15:45:19.742-0700 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27018 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27018 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
```

Do step by step with my instruction you gonna be ok. Good luck and enjoy!!!